# ZTE ZXDSL 831 Series firmware update

Tags: router, firmware, dsl-modem

I'm having a problem with my broadband connection established through a ZTE ZXDSL 831 Series DSL modem and wandered if a firmware update could help me fix that. 
The networking problem is not important at this point but my question is **where to find this modem firmware updates** because [ZTE](http://wwwen.zte.com.cn/en/) does not provide the bits.
Does anyone know where I can find it? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found [this firmware](http://foribb.blogspot.com/2010/09/zte-zxdsl-831aii-modem-router-firmware.html), too, maybe it's one that you could try.

http://dl.box.com/dl/500942674/848f3c9d86b85f6858070241d5f3a62a?a=52a31e1eefd1dd775deabe446201a574&m=10.12.30.52,11211&x=1&c=28367a44048e7faff419b6097764ab54